# How to add dot(.) after every 3 digit?

Tags: objective-c, decimal, formatter

I have number like 2000000 and I want this number in 2.000.000 while displaying. I tried to use number formatter which is provided by iOS SDK `NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle` but it adds comma(,).

Comment: Change the locale of the formatter to one that uses a period (dot) for the separator.  Most European locales will do this.

Comment: @Avi thnx for your reply. But i want dot(.) in every locale not only for European.

Comment: You can set the locale of the formatter.

Comment: @Avi  i set locale to formatter but not get success. Can you please guide me that which locale use dot(.) ?

Comment: @Avi , i got solution. I set locale to "eu" and got result as i want. Thnx for your suggesstion.

Comment: You should update your question with the code you attempted to use so people can help you fix it. Keep that in mind in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `groupingSeparator` property of the `NSNumberFormatter` for that.

**Objective-C**

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.usesGroupingSeparator = YES;
formatter.groupingSeparator = @".";
NSNumber *number = @(2000000);
NSString *string = [formatter stringFromNumber:number];
```

**Swift 2.2**

```
let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
formatter.groupingSeparator = "."
let number = 2000000
let string = formatter.stringFromNumber(number)
```